# "in" or "on" my second week?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use in or on? Or are both okay?

> **A:** I’ll be here for six weeks and I’m already **in** my second week.
>
> **B:** I’ll be here for six weeks and I’m already **on** my second week.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of preposition is likely to depend on the expression or the context.

For example, one is generally:

> in one's first year at university
>   in one's second month of training
>   in one's first week at college
>   in time to write the exam

but

> in / on time for the appointment
>   on a week's holiday
>   on a year's sabbatical
>   on a few days' leave

There is no fixed rule regarding **in** or **on**. At times either may be acceptable; at others the expression, context or idiom dictates the choice.

In answer to your question, you are more likely to be **on** a course **in** your second week

Comment: _on a course_? I don't get that part, and it's not in the OP's sentence. (I assumed it was an internship or something.)

Comment: @J.R. It was my attempt to illustrate how both **on** and **in** could feature in the sentence.

Comment: "on a course" doesn't sound idiomatic; I'd say, "I am in a course in my second week."

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer gives it to **on** by a nose although **in** was preferred historically. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+course%2Cin+a+course&year